# Can non-templated nested classes of class templates be implemented in a C++ header?

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, nested-class

Suppose a header file `myheader.hxx` defines a class template `A` in which a non-templated class `B` is defined (that does not depend on the template parameter of `A`):

```
template<class T>
class A {
    class B { 
        // ...
    };
};
```

Is it okay in this case to implement `B` in `myheader.hxx`, or do I need to write a separate `myheader.cxx` to avoid duplicate definitions at link time? Is this case handeled consistently by different compilers?

Comment: `B` does depend on the template parameter `T` in your example.  Not directly, but `A<int>::B` and `A<double>::B` are unrelated types.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter but I think `typename T` is preferred to `class T` nowadays. At least that's what "the cool kids" seem to do.

Comment: @StephenLin - yes, some people think it's cool to use `typename` here, but `class` is correct, shorter, and it's the way the C++ standard writes templates. There is no good technical reason to use `typename` instead of `class`.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, I know thre's no techical reason, I was being facetious...but `class` is only really allowed for backward compatibility. It would have been a new keyword from the beginning but Bjarne was worried about the possible disruption, and it's clearer to use the new keyword for it now that it exists.

Comment: @StephenLin - it's not clearer, it's just different. As I said, the C++ standard uses `class` everywhere.

Comment: Hah, ok, honestly it's subjective and not a big deal, but it is clearer for people coming from other languages (esp. Java, C#) because otherwise it looks like the parameter could only be a user-defined type (or even only a `class` rather than a `struct`, since C# distinguishes the two). `typename` is more clearly generic. Obviously people reading the C++ Standard know the historical context and it's easier to keep things defined the same way they were there for continuity purposes. libstdc++ and most new libraries use `typename`

Comment: imho, it's also not helpful when people mix the two (using `typename` for generic parameters and `class` when a parameter is meant to be a user-defined parameter, as has sometimes been suggested on SO, because it can propagate the false belief that the distinction is enforced by the compiler. That's why I think it's clearer to use `typename` for new code, but obviously there's no reason to change existing code if you're using `class` consistently and not mixing the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still either a template (or part of template, don't know the ultra-precise definitions) even if it's not the top-level template, so you <s>need to</s> should implement it in the header (technically, it can be in a source file if that's the only place it's used, but that probably defeats the purpose).

Note: if you're not going to implement its member functions inline with the class definition, you need syntax like:

```
template<typename T>
void A<T>::B::foo(...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, because it's come up before, if `B` happened to have its own template parameter, it would be something like:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
void A<T>::B<T2>::foo(...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Not:

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
void A<T>::B<T2>::foo(...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or if `B` didn't but `B::foo` did, it would be:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
// void A<T>::B::foo<T2>(...) // not this apparently
void A<T>::B::foo(...)
{
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**: apparently it's `foo` above instead of `foo<T2>` for a function, at least with GCC (so almost 100% sure that's standard behavior)...I'm sure some language lawyer will be able to explain why :)

Etc.